# How to split long lines to shorter one in VS Codium when one formats the document

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Codium, is it possible to modify the Format Document -command such that it splits for example LaTeX files that has too long lines to two or more lines? Or is there an extension to do that?

Comment: Format Document is based on extensions, you need to find a formatter extension that does this

Comment: @NicolasFormichella That might actually be an answer, you should consider posting it as such.